# Efficient indirect sorting of an array

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting

For example, if an array is stored like this

ex) input

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
7 5 3 9 1 2 4 8 6 0
```

i want to print the idx of the second array in order of magnitude

ex) output

```
3 , 7 , 0 , 8 , 1 , 6 , 2 , 5 , 4 , 9
```

What is an efficient way to do this?

Comment: It is unclear what you are trying to ask...

Comment: use `std::shuffle`

Comment: He is asking hot to carry out an indirect sorting, i.e. leave the elements of the array as they are, but sort an array of indices. Not sure what is not clear in the question.

Answer (score 3):

Assume your numbers are stored in an array `a`:

```
int a[10] = {7, 5, 3, 9, 1, 2, 4, 8, 6, 0};
```

and you want to store the sorted indices in an array `b`, which initially contains all indices in sequential order:

```
int b[10] = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};
```

then you can simply sort the array of indices `b` based on the corresponding value in the array `a`:

```
sort(b, b+10, [a](int i, int j){ return a[i] > a[j]; });
```

Full demo [here](http://cpp.sh/7677te)

Comment: Note that while this solution solves the specific case given in the question, it doesn't address the general problem of indirect sorting, where you want to reorder the elements of one array by a "score" value in another array.  For example, if the value 3 in array b were replaced with 42, a general indirect sorting algorithm would output "42, 7, 0, ...", since the 42 element has the highest score, while the given solution would perform invalid memory accesses, possibly yielding an incorrect answer or segfaulting.